# pdo_pgsql.so and pgsql.so enabled but not showing in phpinfo

Tags: php, postgresql, mamp

I just installed mamp pro on my macbook and i am getting this issue, i have enabled pdo_pgsql.so and pgsql.so as shown here

1.I make sure which php.ini am i using by:

```
macbook@MacBooks-MacBook-Pro ~ % php -i | grep php.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.31/conf
Loaded Configuration File => /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.31/conf/php.ini
nano /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.31/conf/php.ini'
```

2.Then i make sure all files are on the right dir and uncommented

```
extension_dir = "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.31/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/"
extension=pgsql.so
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
```

3.Then i save, close terminal, reboot my MAMP pro, start up my server then i open the phpinfo()
but it says no pdo_pgsql and pgsql at all

I also tried this step https://documentation-5.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/How-Tos/MySQL/Install-PostgreSQL/ but nothing changed

How do i enable the pgsql driver?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, i just update my mamp to newer version